# conditional covariance for a weakly stationary process

Tags: stochastic-processes, conditional-probability, covariance, time-series

Given a stochastic process $\{X_k\}_{k \geq 1}$, we say it is weakly stationary if $\mathbb{E}X_k$ is a constant, and $\mathrm{Cov}(X_k, X_l)$ only depends on $|k - l|$.

My question is, for a weakly stationary process, given any $h \geq 1$, does the conditional covariance $\mathrm{Cov}(X_k, X_{k + h}|X_{k + 1}, \cdots, X_{k + h - 1})$ depend on $k$?

I believe the answer is no if the process is strongly stationary, i.e. the joint probability distribution of a selected set of random variables doesn't change with an index shift. But I am not so sure for a weakly stationary process.

The motivation is that, if the answer to my question is no, then I could define conditional covariance of $X_{k}$ and $X_{k + h}$ from a weakly stationary process as a function of $h$ only.

Answer (score 0):

If a stochastic process $\{X_k\}k≥1$ is weakly stationary, then the conditional covariance $Cov(X_k,X_{k+h}|X_{k+1},⋯,X_{k+h−1})$ does not depend on $k$.

using the definition of weak stationarity and the properties of conditional covariance.

First, we can define weak stationarity as follows:
A process $\{X_k\}k≥1$ is weakly stationary if the mean E[Xk] and the autocovariance function γ(h) = $Cov(Xk,Xk+h)$ are constant for all k and h

Next, we can use the definition of conditional covariance to express $Cov(Xk, Xk+h|Xk+1,⋯, Xk+h−1)$ in terms of the unconditional mean and covariance of the process:

$Cov(Xk,Xk+h|Xk+1,⋯,Xk+h−1) =$
$E[(Xk-E[Xk])(Xk+h-E[Xk+h])|Xk+1,⋯,Xk+h−1]- $ $E[Xk|Xk+1,⋯,Xk+h−1]E[Xk+h|Xk+1,⋯,Xk+h−1]$

Since the mean and autocovariance of the weakly stationary process are constant, the above expression doesn't depend on k.
We know that the conditional mean of Xk given the past values is equal to the unconditional mean since the past values are assumed to be independent of the mean of the process.

And also, the conditional autocovariance is still equal to the unconditional autocovariance function, since the past values are independent of the autocovariance function.
Therefore, the expression for the conditional covariance simplifies to:
$Cov(Xk,Xk+h|Xk+1,⋯,Xk+h−1)$ = γ(h) - E[Xk]E[Xk+h]$

As you can see, this expression does not depend on k, which means that the conditional covariance is a function of h only, as stated before.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can we prove it in a more rigorous way? Although your explanantion makes intuitive sense, I am a bit concerned for just a statement like "conditional covariance is a function of the autocovariance function and the mean".

Comment: You are welcome, I've edited the answer, I hope I explained everything better

Comment: For a weakly stationary process, $\mathrm{E}[X_k]$ doesn't depend on $k$, but how do you justify $\mathrm{E}[X_k|X_{k + 1}, X_{k + 2}]$ doesn't depend on $k$,  I think your argument still doesn't really answer it. With strong stationarity, we know the joint distribution so it's easy, but the assumptions for a weakly stationary process seem to be too simple to say things about $\mathrm{E}[X_k|X_{k + 1}, X_{k + 2}]$.